# Static Content in NancyFX with ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nancy

I'm using Nancy 2.0.0 with ASP.Net Core 2.0.0 and I can't get my application to return static content (in this case, a zip file) from a route defined in a Nancy module.

The Nancy convention is to store static content in `/Content` and the ASP.Net Core convention is to store it in `/wwwroot`, but I can't get my app to recognize either.

My `Startup.Configure` method looks like this:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();            
    app.UseOwin(b => b.UseNancy());
}
```

And my module route looks like this:

```cs
Get("/big_file", _ => {
    return Response.AsFile("wwwroot/test.zip");
});
```

But Nancy always returns a 404 when I hit this route. I've also tried directing ASP.Net Core to the static directory expected by Nancy, like this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Content")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Content")
});
```

But this didn't work either. I've tried putting the file in `/Content` and in `/wwwroot` with the same result. And I've tried different casing of `Content`, but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was that I needed to let Nancy know what I wanted to use as the root path for the application. I did this by creating a class that inherits from `IRootPathProvider`. Nancy will discover any class that inherits from this on Startup, so you can put it wherever you want.

```
public class DemoRootPathProvider : IRootPathProvider
{
  public string GetRootPath()
  {
    return Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
  }
}
```

Once this was in place I was able to access static content in `/Content`. Additionally, I was able to add additional static directories (for example, if I wanted to stick with `/wwwroot`) by adding a class that inherits from `DefaultNancyBootstrapper`. Again, Nancy will find this on Startup, so you can put it anywhere.

```
public class DemoBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
  protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions conventions)
  {
    base.ConfigureConventions(conventions);

    conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(
        StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("wwwroot")
    );
  }
}
```